# Случайный набор не на том языке, автоисправление

Tags: c#

Необходима функция исправления случайно набранных символов на другом языке, в данном случае `EN->RU`, также удаление букв `ё` и `Ё`. Вот что написал я:

```
string eng = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>`~ёЁ";
string ru =  "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮеЕеЕ";
for (int i = 0; i < eng.Length; ++i)
  if (query.Contains(eng[i]))
    query = query.Replace(eng[i], ru[i]);
```

Очень не нравится код, кто бы мог помочь?

Comment: почему не нравится? чем помочь?

Comment: Быдлянский код какой-то, есть ли более изящные решения?

Comment: Создай массив, где индекс равен неправильному коду символа, а значение - правильному (например, код "й" равен 223, код "q" равен 113, т.к. надо менять "q" на "й", то `tab[113]=223`), и заменяй по нему. Само собой, для "правильных" индекс равен значению, т.е. `tab[223]=223`. Ну или то же, но в форме строкового литерала, где на позиции, равной коду неверного символа, стоИт символ верный - но это будет медленнее.

Comment: @Akina боюсь для UTF-8 будет слишком тяжелый массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public sealed class Replacer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Char, Char> _dictionary;

    public Replacer(String sourceSymbols, String targetSymbols)
    {
        if (sourceSymbols.Length != targetSymbols.Length)
            throw new NotSupportedException("sourceSymbols.Length != targetSymbols.Length");

        Int32 count = sourceSymbols.Length;

        Dictionary<Char, Char> dictionary = new Dictionary<Char, Char>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            dictionary.Add(sourceSymbols[i], targetSymbols[i]);

        _dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public void FixCharacters(ref String query)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            return;

        if (String.IsInterned(query) == null)
        {
            FixNotInternedString(query);
        }
        else
        {
            FixInternedString(ref query);
        }
    }

    private unsafe void FixNotInternedString(String query)
    {
        Int32 index = query.Length - 1;
        fixed (Char* chPtr = query)
        {
            while (index >= 0)
            {
                Char oldChar = chPtr[index];

                Char newChar;
                if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(oldChar, out newChar))
                    chPtr[index] = newChar;

                index--;
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixInternedString(ref String query)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(query.Length);
        foreach (Char c in query)
        {
            Char fixedChar;
            if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(c, out fixedChar))
                sb.Append(fixedChar);
            else
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        query = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String eng = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>`~ёЁ";
    String rus = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮеЕеЕ";

    Replacer replacer = new Replacer(eng, rus);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        String query = $"Hello World {i}";

        replacer.FixCharacters(ref query);

        Console.WriteLine(query); // "Руддщ Цщкдв"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1).** Можно создать из строк `eng` и `ru` словарь "EN->RU", после чего проходить по заданной строке и заменять каждый символ в соответствии со словарём. В этом случае не придётся многократно просматривать изначальную строку, а создаваться будет всего одна новая строка:

```
public static class LangConversion
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, char> engToRu = new Dictionary<char, char>();

    static LangConversion()
    {
        var eng = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>`~ёЁ";
        var ru = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮеЕеЕ";
        for (var i = 0; i < eng.Length; i++)
            engToRu[eng[i]] = ru[i];
    }

    public static string Fix(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            char fixedChar;
            sb.Append(engToRu.TryGetValue(c, out fixedChar) ? fixedChar : c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

**2).** Если производительность важнее изящества кода, то можно замену реализовать с помощью switch-case:

```
public static class LangConversion2
{
    public static string Fix(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            sb.Append(Replace(c));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static char Replace(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'q': return 'й';
            ...
            case 'Ё': return 'Е';
            default: return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Полное содержимое `switch` [в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1a0qujg2/).

---

**3).** Ещё один способ провести замену при небольших дополнительных затратах памяти - с помощью массива:

```
public static class LangConversion3
{
    private static readonly char[] engToRu;

    static LangConversion3()
    {
        var eng = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>`~ёЁ";
        var ru = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮеЕеЕ";
        int maxCharCode = 0;
        foreach (char c in eng)
            maxCharCode = c > maxCharCode ? c : maxCharCode;
        engToRu = new char[maxCharCode + 1];
        for (var i = 0; i < eng.Length; i++)
            engToRu[eng[i]] = ru[i];
    }

    public static string Fix(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            sb.Append(Replace(c));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static char Replace(char c)
    {
        if (c >= engToRu.Length)
            return c;
        var fixedChar = engToRu[c];
        return fixedChar != 0 ? fixedChar : c;
    }
}
```

---

Замеры скорости работы на строке в 100 тысяч символов при 1000 итераций:

```
Исходный вариант:               6480мс
Dictionary:                     2550мс
Pointers (ответ @LunarWhisper): 1560мс
Switch-case:                    1520мс
Array:                          1310мс
Pointers + array:                720мс
Pointers + switch-case:          580мс
```

Comment: Я так полагаю без словаря никак =)

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик со словарём, по крайней мере, выходит быстрее, хоть и в моём варианте прирост производительности вышел не сильно-то большой.

Comment: Да! Отличный прирост! Спасибо за вариант, сравнил с ответом Lunar Whisper, там на четверть быстрее! +1 за ответ Вам, спасибо!

Comment: @Regent Попробуй передать в StringBuilder длину строки. Думаю, после этого твой вариант приблизится по скорости к моему.

Comment: @LunarWhisper уже попробовал. Надо будет в ответ добавить (всё-таки так быстрее), но прирост скорости вышел совсем уж незначительный.

Comment: @LunarWhisper занятно, кстати, выглядят результаты вашего варианта, разогнанного с помощью switch-case.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик получилось ещё два варианта без `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Regent думаю, можно ещё пометить метод `Replace` аттрибутом `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`. В случае switch-case он скорее всего не будет автоматически встроен компилятором из-за большого размера. Кстати, ты же в релизной сборке смотришь?

Comment: почему разработчики путают (ненужную) производительность и красоту кода?

Comment: я к тому, что есть же .ToDictionary(), Max(), есть в конце концов out *char* fixedChar - но нет, все равно надо писать в стиле C# 2.0, циклами, ручной работой с индексами - чтобы те, кому придется этот код читать, не расслаблялись! :)

Comment: Ух, даже не думал что данная задача так Вас зацепит... Кстати по поводу реплейсов, необходимо будет выполнять данный код ооочень много раз, скорость для меня критична. Не могу сказать почему, но поверьте это так =).

Comment: @PashaPash Это просто императивный подход против функционально-декларативного программирования. Последнее чаще всего отталкивает тем, что ты либо не понимаешь, как оно работает, либо понимаешь и тебе это совсем не нравится. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper нет, это в debug-e, чтобы компилятор ничего лишнего не заоптимизировал и можно было оценить алгоритмы "как есть". Понятно, что из-за этого результаты замеров выходят отчасти теоретические, но всё же. Можно попробовать прогнать все варианты в release-е и добавить в конец ответа.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик да, у меня с десяток ответов есть с различными алгоритмами и замерами скорости их работы. А тут представилась ещё такая возможность, особенно учитывая что вариант с `Dictionary` достаточно плохо себя показал

Comment: @Regent, обрати внимание, я поправил свой вариант. Спасибо за замечание. Обязательно нужно проверить, что строки не интерниированы, иначе мы рискуем изменить строку, которая этого совсем не ожидает. :)

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of software engineering is to control complexity, not to create it

Отсутствие четких критериев красоты "по виду" обычно приводит к исправлению в сторону "красивого" сложного кода. Отдельные классы-реплейсеры, нативная работа с Char (которая неизвестно как отработает на суррогатных парах), string builder-ы - вот это все.

Отсутсвие четких критериев красоты "по скорости" обычно приводит к "оптимизации" там, где она не нужна. У вас код исправления "случайно набранных символов на другом языке". Давайте проверять его на строках длиной в 100 000 символов на 1000 итераций! Пользователи же каждый день пишут Войну и Мир, забыв переключить раскладку. И потом огорчаются, что код работает *аж 6 миллисекунд* для исправления этой ошибки. 0.5 ms для них - ощутимая разница!

В вашем случае:

- К коду нет строгих (реально обоснованных, а не "было бы круто") требований по производительности, нет четких требований по красоте (imho, код, который эту задачу решает больше, чем за 10 строк - ужасен!)
- Нет требований по памяти (ваш вариант, например, потратит `(размер строки)^2` байт, причем мусор будет выбрасываться сразу же, и дальше gen 0 не уйдет).

Единственное оставшееся требование - **читабельность**. Она же поддерживаемость.

Читабельность можно измерить стадартными метриками. Та же студия умеет считать Code Metrics.

Так вот, при условии что eng / ru объявлены как статика, по [Maintainability 
 Index](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2011/05/26/code-metrics-maintainability-index/) выигрывают два варианта:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eng.Length; ++i)
    query = query.Replace(eng[i], ru[i]);
```

и чуть более новый, но такой же по сути

```
// считаем один раз, оптимизация!
static (char, char)[] dictionary = eng.Zip(ru, (a, b) => (a, b)).ToArray();

//....

foreach (var (e, r) in dictionary)
    query = query.Replace(e, r);
```

Оно же с инлайном:

```
foreach (var (e, r) in eng.Zip(ru, (a, b) => (a, b)))
    query = query.Replace(e, r);
```

В поставленных вами рамках, все остальные варианты - баловство.

Comment: К сожалению, Char в .NET не поддерживает суррогатные пары. Убедиться в этом можно, простой итерацией по строке `"_\ud800\udc00_"`, поэтому результат для обоих случаев будет идентичен - это не будет работать ни в каком виде, пока бы работаем на уровне символов, и не опустились к байтам.

По существу верно, но насчёт читабельности последнего решения я бы поспорил. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper а в чем проблема с читабельностью последнего (предпоследнего) решения? Там две строчки всего, не эзотерика, не какой-то code golf - обычный цикл с реплейсом. Просто некоторые так и не смогли принять всей душой linq (и даже foreach-и), не доверяют компилятору вывод типов, и предпочитают "ручной режим". Например, любой современный js-ник или питонщик такое легко прочитает, даже не зная C#. Чем не показатель читабельности?

Comment: Видимо из-за анонимных типов. Последнее решение читается на порядок лучше. Но опять же - предложенный вариант замены с итерацией по строке N раз, где N - размер словаря... а зачем? Потом этот же код будет скопипащен в другой метод, который будет заниматься заменой тегов в 500мб XML-файле и привет. О.о Когда речь идёт о линейной зависимости - O(N) или O(3N) - можно выбрать любой вариант. Но специально впарываться в O(N*M)? Так и до (N^M) не далеко. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper Затем, что на написание этого метода я потратил десяток секунд. Это простой, читабельный вариант, который решает поставленную топикастером задачу "Случайный набор не на том языке, автоисправление". И ни один из альтернативных вариантов не решает ее проще или быстрее. Зачем впарываться в 20+ строк с unsafe, если то же самое можно решить вручную.  Если вы скопипастите его в замену тегов в 500 Mb XML - вы сразу же поймете, что сделали что-то не так. Можно впарываться хоть в O(n^6), если реальное время работы на максимальном N - миллисекунды.

Comment: @LunarWhisper YAGNI. Нельзя писать код основываясь на "а если" и придумывая условия на ходу. А если этот код надо запускать на машине без .NET? А если его придется запускать на компьютере шаттла? Маловероятно? Я за много лет работы парсил на C# XML размером 500 Mb ровно *0* раз. *Неразумно* писать **каждую строчку** кода с расчетом на все сложные ситуации, которые мне ни разу не встретились вживую :)

Comment: не могу не согласиться - оверинженеринг, безусловно, зло. Но мне кажется, что вначале нужно научиться писать простой, но быстрый универсальный код, а уже затем, исходя из собственного опыта, сознательно жертвовать чем-то для простоты написания и удобства поддержки. Иначе молодые специалисты, привыкшие писать простой, но медленный код, начинают писать парсеры с использованием dynamic'ов и строят Linq для работы с файловой системой, и стреляет это непременно в продакшене, когда выясняется, что решение абсолютно не скейлится и нужно всё переписывать.

Comment: @LunarWhisper не бывает *универсального* кода. Бывает код, который решает конкретную задачу, и код, который ее не решает. Нельзя придумывать аргументы для усложения кода с потолка. "надо писать реплейс символов на 20+ строк вместо двух" потому что "потом понапишете парсеров с динамиками и все упорете" - это не аргумент. Нельзя заранее предугадать все возможные проблемы с производительностью. Разработчик должен уметь выражать в коде суть происходящего. Если для выражения одной и той же сути понадобилось в 10 раз больше строк и указатели - значит суть выражена не слишком хорошо :)

Comment: Предугадать нельзя, но предположить можно. И есть на входе есть словарь произвольной длины и строка произвольной длины, то можно предположить, что и тот и другая могут быть достаточно большими, чтобы это создало проблемы. Для того, чтобы код оставался опрятным и читабельным, у нас есть классы, которые инкапсулируют эту логику и снаружи выглядят, как replacer.Replace(str) и это ещё короче, чем вышеописанные Linq. А ещё в мире набирает популярность разработка через тестирование. А это значит, что у этого класса ещё может появиться набор тестов. И на фоне этого массива кода... ;)

Comment: Ну ок, мы предположили что будет словарь длины не больше 104 (или сколько там кнопок на клавиатуре) и строка не больше 100000 символов. Можно написать один тест + две строчки, которые будут работать мгновенно на этих объемах. И пойти дальше - это подход YAGNI, который я пытаюсь вам объяснить. Можно написать 20 строчек с native code, инкапсулировать их в класс, написать пачку тестов, включая "а что если строки не совпадут", вставить его через IoC, и при этом создать опасный сайдеэффект, который почти нереально отладить - это ваш вариант. Я, пожалуй, выберу свой.

Comment: @LunarWhisper т.е. ок, хотите быстрое и красивое решение - напишите код на три строки с ToDictionary + Select. Оно будет лучше, быстрее и безглючнее, чем вариант с пойнтерами

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63675/discussion-between-pashapash-and-lunar-whisper).